# Can the dependency flow be configured for Sonar Design view?

Tags: sonarqube

The way I understand, the point of the Design View is to highlight cyclic dependencies and to lead us to a low package tangle index.

When it comes to configuration, I wonder if can create 'rules' that would allow me to deny package dependencies.

Say I have project structure like this:

```
src
  main
    java
com
  whatever
    model/......
    business/...
```

My goal is to let business use classes from the model package, but not the other way around.

**Note**: 
I understand that by proper modularization and dependency setup I could restrict this during build time.

My question is if a situation is given can I tell Sonar to shout if there are forbidden references based on my rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [Architectural Constraint](http://nemo.sonarqube.org/coding_rules#rule_key=squid%3AArchitecturalConstraint) rule that's available for Java. It should do what you need.